# How to allow writing to a mounted NFS partition

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, nfs, fedora

How do you allow a specific user permission to write to an NFS partition?

I've mounted an NFS share on my localhost (a Fedora install), and I can read and write as root, but I'm unable to write as the apache user, even though all the files and directories in the share on my localhost and remote host are owned by apache.

For example, I've mounted it via this line in my /etc/fstab:

```
remotehost:/data/media     /data/media             nfs     _netdev,soft,intr,rw,bg        0 0
```

And both locations are owned by apache:

```
[root@remotehost ~]# ls -la /data
total 24
drwxr-xr-x.  6 root    root    4096 Jan  6  2011 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 28 root    root    4096 Oct 31  2011 ..
drwxr-xr-x   4 apache  apache  4096 Jan 14  2011 media

[root@localhost ~]# ls -la /data
total 16
drwxr-xr-x   4 apache apache 4096 Dec  7  2011 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 27 root   root   4096 Jun 11 15:51 ..
drwxrwxrwx   5 apache apache 4096 Jan 31  2011 media
```

However, when I try and write as the apache user, I get a "Permission denied" error.

```
[root@localhost ~]# sudo -u apache touch /data/media/test.txt'
touch: cannot touch `/data/media/test.txt': Permission denied
```

But of course it works fine as root. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `/etc/exports` say on the server?

Answer (score 4):

NFS authorizes operations based on the user ID, not username. To be able to write to `/data/media` on NFS client you need to ensure that `apache` on `localhost` and `apache` on `remotehost` have the same numeric user IDs.

File listings in the post do not confirm that.

Indeed the `localhost` listing says that the *mountpoint* `/data/media` is owned by apache@localhost.

```
[root@localhost ~]# ls -la /data
 ...
 drwxrwxrwx   5 apache apache 4096 Jan 31  2011 media
```

The remote listing shows that *shared resource* `/data/media` is owned by apache@remotehost.

```
[root@remotehost ~]# ls -la /data
drwxr-xr-x   4 apache  apache  4096 Jan 14  2011 media
```

If numeric user IDs of apache@localhost and apache@remotehost differ the directory would not be writable.

You can use the command `ls -lna` to check numerical user IDs.

**This is just a guess.** There is nothing in the OP that specifically confirms that there is a disagreement in user IDs.

Comment: The uid is 48 on both hosts, but the gid is 492 on my localhost but 487 on the remotehost.

Comment: @Cerin looks like my guess is wrong. I'll keep the answer for a while in case someone else comes up with a similar idea.

Answer (score 0):

- Is the export writeable (check `/etc/exports` on the server)? 
  As you'll find in `exports(5)`:

  ```
     rw     Allow both read and write requests on this NFS volume.
            The default is to disallow any request which changes the filesystem.
            This can also be made explicit by using the ro option.
  ```
- (Probably not relevant, but I don't know much about the existing SELinux policies) Are you using SELinux on the server? You can check with `getenforce`, might want to try again after `setenforce 0` (undo with `setenforce 1`).
- I did note that the UIDs happen to match. But I believe it's worth mentioning that to make sure users and groups are matched by names instead of IDs, you can configure the `idmap` service on both hosts.